# Phonegap check android device status

Tags: cordova, nfc, phonegap-plugins

I developed Android phonegap application.

my app need check `Device NFC Status` (Enabled or Disabled)

I use [Phonegap nfc-plugin](https://github.com/chariotsolutions/phonegap-nfc) but this plugin not support that.

How to check device nfc status via phonegap?

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to build a new plugin using native code.

Comment: @QuickFix me too.. I guess, there is no way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Android, the plugin checks the NFC status on every Cordova API call.

https://github.com/chariotsolutions/phonegap-nfc/blob/0.4.8/src/android/src/com/chariotsolutions/nfc/plugin/NfcPlugin.java#L68

If the device does not have NFC, the error handler will receive NO_NFC. If NFC is disabled the error handler will receive NFC_DISABLED.

https://github.com/chariotsolutions/phonegap-nfc/blob/0.4.8/src/android/src/com/chariotsolutions/nfc/plugin/NfcPlugin.java#L47

Comment: This work, but, if the NFC is enabled after application is running the plugin does not check for it and trigger always NFC_DISABLED, if you close (destroy) the application and run again work.